# creating a button/link with Json params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby-on-rails-3

I got this in a controller:

```
def create
if save
respond_to do |format|
     format.html { render "crop" }
     format.json { render json: @user, status: :updated, location: @user, notice: "updated" }
end
end
```

The above respond_to will render .com/user/:id (users/crop.html.erb)

Instead of rendering crop.html.erb after create method, I need a link which would take user to the same page.

```
<%=link_to "crop", render "crop", render json: @user, location: @user %> <- don't know whow to write this one.
```

Would anyone be so kind to educate me ? :) please

Comment: `link_to 'crop', some_url(status: :updated, location: @user, notice: "updated")` works not?

Comment: I don't have 'some_url', got a stray "crop.html.erb" which does render with the above format.

Comment: in that case I'm not sure what's the question. Maybe try it rephrase it?

Comment: edited the original question as best i could