# How to use an object value as the href attribute of an element with AngularJS?

Tags: html, json, angularjs

AnglarJS newb here looking for some answers. I have these files,and HTML and a JSON file, what I want to do is use a link stablished as an attribute in the json and use it in a button or link tag.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src=          "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="templateApp" ng-controller="templateCtrl"> 

<ul>
<li ng-repeat="x in templates">
{{ x.title}}
</li>
<li ng-repeat="x in templates">
{{ x.limagen}}
</li>
<li ng-repeat="x in templates">
    {{x.lpagina}}
</li>

<a href ng-click="lpagina">
    <script>
            lpagina={{x.lpagina}};
    </script>

    Link</a>

</ul>

<img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?  txtsize=25&txt=400%C3%97100&w=400&h=100"></img>

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('templateApp', []);
app.controller('templateCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
$http.get("obras.json")
.success(function (response) {$scope.templates = response.obra;});
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

And the json file (obras.json)

```
    {
   "obra": [
       {
           "title": "Sample Text",
           "limagen": "http://placehold.it/350x150",
           "lpagina": "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25335140/creating-    a-button-link-with-json-params"
       }
   ]

}
```

Thanks for any help you can give me!

Comment: I'm starting my comments over because I'm confused about what you're trying to accomplish. Please update your question with an example of the final HTML you want. There are several issues here, starting with the odd script inside the anchor.

Comment: I want to use the value lpagina of the json in a button or href in the html, what I did with the <a href> tag was a failed test

Comment: It sounds like you might need to use ng-href.

Comment: I understand that, but I was trying to help clean up the other issues you have here. The href attribute is trivial once the other stuff is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular allows `{{ }}` inside of the tags as well. You also don't need to write this as a script since it is just an anchor tag.

```
<a href ng-click="lpagina">
  <script>
        lpagina={{x.lpagina}};
  </script>

Link</a>
```

Becomes:

```
<a href="{{x.lpagina}}">Link</a>
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/8qv6cbhd/)**

Comment: I had a fiddle ready so I added it here. Notice that I've moved the ng-repeat to the list.

Comment: And the rest of the code remains the same? Just put the updated a ref tag inside the div? Thanks for the answer!

Comment: No, you also need to remove the extra script, move your anchor *inside* the list item (for valid html), and fix the ng-repeat structure. See the fiddle.

Comment: Holy Sh*t! It worked!, mind explaining me in short terms what did you do and why? Thanks so much! And if i want to load the data from a Json in a server like in the original code? Thanks!!

Comment: Thanks for the demo. I thought that might be the end goal but wasn't sure. Really makes the answer clear. @GaboNúñez check out the docs for [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http). You will need to write a [service](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) for the controller to subscribe to as well.